# Square character issue for Urdu language to wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed wkhtmltopdf on **Ubuntu 12.04**. Whenever i generate PDF for **Urdu** text using wkhtmltopdf some square characters are displayed in PDF. As per my analysis this is not an UTF-8 issue because PDF get generate correctly for English, Marathi, Hindi, Arabic and Oriya languages. I have also installed **ttf-Nafees font** on ubuntu. Still square characters get displayed in PDF.

Sample image is given below for reference.

[image]

Comment: It probably is an UTF-8 issue (or a font related one). BTW, Ubuntu-12 is an ancient distribution. Consider upgrading to the current [Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), which has probably better UTF-8 support

Comment: I have try same thing on ubuntu desktop 16.04. Everything working fine on it but when i try it on ubuntu server 16.04 its not working.

Comment: Even Ubuntu 16 is old. The current one is 18.04.1 and I would suppose that support for rare languages has *recently* improved